# Chartjs - How to update the data from values in my database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I am having some issues trying to update my Chartjs doughnut chart using data pulled from my database.

I have the following ajax call which is successful:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "<!--#include virtual="../include/env"-->/data",
    type: "GET",
    cache: "false",
    success: function(value) {
      update_doughnut(value);
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
```

This pulls in 2 values [used and free]
The JS for my chart looks like this currently:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myDoughnutChart').getContext('2d');
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Used', 'Free'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 0],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
  ],
  borderWidth: 2
  }]
},
options: {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
},
});
```

I have tried creating this function which the ajax calls to update the data:

```
function table_space(value) {
    myDoughnutChart.data.datasets[0].data = [value[0].USED, value[0].FREE]

    myDoughnutChart.update();
  };
```

But I keep getting a "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error message. It is worth noting that the query that the ajax call runs can take up 40secs; could this be why?

Comment: Try using setInterval of one minute, also add this to console log and check what is held in the object

Comment: where would I put the set interval? Also do you believe my code is correct? I am still unable to determine whether it is the fault of my code or if the query can take some time?

Comment: its unclear when you are calling ajax function, in the your table_space function. can you console log myDoughnutChart.data.datasets and see what is available here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. But managed to figure it out. I need to make changes to my Ajax call to update the values of my doughnuts directly and get rid of my table_space function:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "<!--#include virtual="../include/env"-->/data",
        type: "GET",
        cache: "false",
        success: function(value) {
        Doughnut1.data.datasets[0].data = [value[0].USED, value[0].FREE]
        Doughnut2.data.datasets[0].data = [value[1].USED, value[1].FREE]
        Doughnut3.data.datasets[0].data = [value[2].USED, value[2].FREE]
        Doughnut1.update();
        Doughnut2.update();
        Doughnut3.update();
      },
        dataType: "json"
      });
```